# IIS URL Rewrite remove folder and redirect to other domain

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, rule

I have two domains, www.example.com and www.example.xx.

When I'm visiting example.com and change language, my adress changes to example.com/xx. In this case I want to redirect do another domain suffix like example.xx instead. But I still want to forward the full address path.

For example: http://example.com/xx/one/two/three/four/five/?query=string should redirect to http://example.xx/one/two/three/four/five/?query=string

I have tried several ways, but with no luck.

```html
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name=".com xx Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(www\.)?example\.com\/xx\/.*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^xx\/(.*)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.xx/{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Temporary" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

match url only matches the path not the domain. You will have to do something like this:

```
<rule name=".com xx Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^xx/(.*)" />
<conditions >
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />

</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://example.xx/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen! That solved my problem. Finally, after a full day's effort.

Comment: After testing the changes I realized that this won't work if you have the following link example http://example.com/one/two/xx/three/four/five/?query=string. In this case you will get directed to the folloing address http://example.xx/three/four/five/?query=string without folder one and two.

Comment: With the addition of the following line in conditions, the problem was solved.
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^\/xx" />